# Using a clock in/out timer and displaying the time elapsed

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application that is supposed to simulate an employee clocking in and out of work. Clicking clock in will start a timer, and when clock out is clicked, it will end the timer and display how much time is elapsed in the result boxes below. This is probably a really simple task for most people, but I don't have a lot of knowledge or experience with using dates, times, timers, etc., so I don't know what to code for this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you check out the stopwatch class for C#. As you can see in the example below, the format comes out as Hours, Minutes, Seconds, Milliseconds, you could then parse that outputted string to display appropriately inside your timeclock visual. I hope that helps!

[Here is a link to the relevant documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.start?view=netframework-4.8)

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        stopWatch.Stop();
        // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

        // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);
        Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of a time clock I would use the DateTime. This way you'll have the date and time of your clock punches. Simply call DateTime.Now for in/out and read the TimeSpan parameters as needed.

```
DateTime clockIn = new DateTime(2020, 02, 12, 8, 0, 0);
DateTime clockOut = new DateTime(2020, 02, 12, 16, 30, 0);
TimeSpan timeWorked = clockOut - clockIn;

// Time worked = 8 hours, 30 minutes
string timeWorkedReport = $"Time worked = {timeWorked.Hours} hours, {timeWorked.Minutes} minutes";
```